# Difference between $? and $LastExitCode in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

In PowerShell, what is the difference between `$?` and `$LastExitCode`?

I read about [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), and it said:

> `$?  Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.`
>
> `$LastExitCode Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.`

In the definition of `$?` it doesn't explain what succeed and fail mean.

---

I ask because I presumed that `$?` is True if and only if $LastExitCode is 0, but I found a surprising counter-example: *[$LastExitCode=0 but $?=False in PowerShell. Redirecting stderr to stdout gives NativeCommandError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101)*.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`$LastExitCode` is the return code of native applications. `$?` just returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the last command (cmdlet or native) exited without error or not.

For cmdlets failure usually means an exception, for native applications it's a non-zero exit code:

```
PS> cmd /c "exit 5"
PS> $?
False
PS> cmd /c "exit 0"
PS> $?
True
```

Cancelling a cmdlet with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will also count as failure; for native applications it depends on what exit code they set.

Comment: Thanks Joey. I myself thought $? meant non-zero exit code, but I've just found a surprising counterexample. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101/powershell-lastexitcode-0-but-false-redirecting-stderr-to-stdout-gives-nat

Comment: That's an interesting one. I would believe this to be a bug (because it behaves inconsistently between different PowerShell hosts).

Comment: And different cmdlets: @iex abcde@ for instance returns neither $?=False or $LastExitCode > 0