# What does "$?" mean in PowerShell

Tags: variables, powershell, error-handling, powershell-2.0

I'm very new to PowerShell. While looking up information about error handling I've found a lot of references to using "$?"

I know that it has something to do with errors but what exactly is it? And where can I read more about it?

All of my Google searches have found nothing.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666035/powershell-difference-between-and-lastexitcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after asking this I discovered the command
"Get-Help -name about_automatic_variables"

This gives information about every automatic variable in powershell, it's very helpful

Comment: That command doesn't work for me `Get-Help could not find about_automatic_variables in a help file in this session.` That's PowerShell 3 on Windows 8.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn, have you run `update-help`? It works for me on v3/Win7.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Sorry, I should have added that I was running this on PowerShell 2.0  
Also I used the command "Get-Help -Name *" at the end of the list it had HelpFiles that describe a lot of things

Comment: @SSAdministrator no problem, it was my fault since I hadn't updated my help files.

Comment: It’s also online at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables

Answer (score 11):

From the [The Essential Windows PowerShell Cheat Sheet](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/windows-powershell):

*Errors and Debugging: The success or failure status of the last command can be determined by checking $?*

Example:

```
> Get-Content file-that-exists.txt
Hello world
> Write-Host $?
True
> Get-Content file-that-does-not-exist.txt
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\file-that-does-not-exist.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content file-that-does-not-exist.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\file-that-does-not-exist.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
> Write-Host $?
False
```

Comment: Do you know of any place that has more documentation on it? Or is it just that simple that it doesn't need more documentation?

Comment: @SSAdministrator it is that easy, its boolean. So you can use it in all sorts of fun ways, like `If (!($?)) {Create-File $SomeFile}